# flutter is there one correct way to implement BLoC?

Tags: flutter, bloc

Hey i am developing a flutter app that relies on firestore and firebase as a backend and am implementu=ing BLoC in it i have just started and got the idea of BLoC but i have noticed that each tutorial or video or course online implements it with different ways some people use the bloc package some people use rxDart and some dont . for me am creating the blocs manually based on what i need . so can anyone explain to me if there is a one approach to do this or i can keep on working with the way that suits me ?

Comment: At this point in time, "bloc" doesn't mean anything anymore. Anything that is about separation of concern is called "bloc" by the community... So your call

Comment: oh that puts some ideas in mind so what you are saying as long as i am following some business logic separation in the app and it suits me then the community calls that bloc and not necessarily be one way or another right ? @RémiRousselet

Comment: maybe "bloc" does not have a well defined meaning, but it is common they involve `Stream`. `rxDart` is nothing special. It is just a wrapper for native dart stream api and provide some utility functions that perhaps users from the reactiveX series such as `rxjs`, feel comfortable to use. "bloc" never limit which package to use as long as you have some channels for the ui and the business logic to talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLoC is a pattern and the core basically is to separate you `UI` and `Business Logic`. How you UI will communicate with you BLoC, you can implement this the different ways.

[Image illustrating BLoC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywDor.png)

Comment: thanks based on your answer and @Rémi Rousselet  answer i get the idea now